# Using LINQ or similar method to get cell data from Xtragrid

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm usig Xtragrid in one of my forms and i would like to read data from one of its cells.Normally you use 
`gridView_Test_Values.GetRowCellValue([rowhandle][columnname]` 
to get the data.That works great if you know the row handle.What i want to achieve is,i would like to get the data from my cell based on a value from another cell a,that's of course in another column,and the row handle of that row is changeable.Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Can try in this way

```
private [YourObjectInGrid] GetSelected() {
    var selectedRows = view.GetSelectedRows();
    if (selectedRows != null && selectedRows.Length > 0) {
        var o = view.GetRow(selectedRows[0]);
        if (o != null) {
          return o as [YourObjectInGrid];
        }
    }
}
```

You can create [NonPersistent] calculate field in your data model, and use it in your grid.

```
  [NonPersistent]
  public string Name {
   get {
    try {
       return (FirstName + " " + LastName).Trim();
    }
    catch { }
    return String.Empty;
   }
  }
```